# How to read the Mifare Classic tag using the NfcA class?

Tags: android, authentication, nfc, mifare, low-level

I have an NFC tag with support for `NfcA` and `MifareClassic` technologies. After a firmware update, my phone does not support the `MifareClassic` technology anymore. On older firmware, reading the `MifareClassic` tag worked fine.

Is it possible to use the `NfcA` class to read the Mifare Classic tag? How can this be done?

The key for authenticating the technology of Mifare Classic A0A1A2A3A4A5 (For example)

```
public static String[] readTag(Tag tag) {
    byte[] readedData;
    byte[] PASSWORD = new byte[]{(byte) 0xA0, (byte) 0xA1, (byte) 0xA2, (byte) 0xA3, (byte) 0xA4, (byte) 0xA5};
    NfcA nfca = NfcA.get(tag);
    try {

        nfca.connect();
        readedData = nfca.transceive(new byte[]{
                (byte) 0x30,
                (byte) (0 & 0x0ff),PASSWORD // (for example)
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

[Commands for transceive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1HMM.png)

Comment: Why don't you use the high-level interface provided by the `MifareClassic` tag technology instance?

Comment: @MichaelRoland It is necessary, to implement additional functions, thank you. And I do not know how to implement it, I hope for your help.

Comment: What additional functionality would you want to implement for mifare classic that's not already covered by the MifareClassic tag technology?

Comment: @MichaelRoland My phone does not support the Mifare Classic reading technology (on the new firmware). If you implement reading through the NFCA class. Will it work? On older firmware, reading the MifareClassic tag worked fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, in order to communicate (i.e. authenticate, perform read/write operations) with MIFARE Classic tags, you will need a device with NFC hardware that supports MIFARE Classic. Due to NXP's licensing policies, this is typically only possible on devices with NFC chipsets from NXP. Other NFC chipsets will usually only allow you to perform anti-collision and enumeration (i.e. detect the tag and read its (N)UID).

Since you indicated that the capability to access MIFARE Classic (through the `MifareClassic` tag technology object) was lost as a result of a firmware update, I would assume that your NFC chipset is capable of accessing MIFARE Classic.

NXP's NFC controllers transparently abstract access to MIFARE Classic tags with MIFARE reader commands (plain-text commands for authentication, binary read/write, and value block operations). The chipset automatically takes care of translating these abstract commands to actual MIFARE Classic commands, mutual authentication, and session encryption. The `MifareClassic` tag technology object implements the following commands:

- `authenticateSectorWithKeyA(sectorIndex, key)`:

  ```
  +----------+-------------+--------------------+-------------------+
  |   0x60   | BLOCK_INDEX | UID (last 4 bytes) |       KEY_A       |
  | (1 byte) |  (1 byte)   |     (4 bytes)      |     (6 bytes)     |
  +----------+-------------+--------------------+-------------------+
  ```
- `authenticateSectorWithKeyB(sectorIndex, key)`:

  ```
  +----------+-------------+--------------------+-------------------+
  |   0x61   | BLOCK_INDEX | UID (last 4 bytes) |       KEY_B       |
  | (1 byte) |  (1 byte)   |     (4 bytes)      |     (6 bytes)     |
  +----------+-------------+--------------------+-------------------+
  ```
- `readBlock(blockIndex)`:

  ```
  +----------+-------------+
  |   0x30   | BLOCK_INDEX |
  | (1 byte) |  (1 byte)   |
  +----------+-------------+
  ```
- `writeBlock(sectorIndex, data)`:

  ```
  +----------+-------------+--------------------+
  |   0xA0   | BLOCK_INDEX |        DATA        |
  | (1 byte) |  (1 byte)   |     (16 bytes)     |
  +----------+-------------+--------------------+
  ```
- `increment(blockIndex, value)`:

  ```
  +----------+-------------+-------------------+
  |   0xC1   | BLOCK_INDEX |       VALUE       |
  | (1 byte) |  (1 byte)   |     (4 bytes)     |
  +----------+-------------+-------------------+
  ```
- `decrement(blockIndex, value)`:

  ```
  +----------+-------------+-------------------+
  |   0xC0   | BLOCK_INDEX |       VALUE       |
  | (1 byte) |  (1 byte)   |     (4 bytes)     |
  +----------+-------------+-------------------+
  ```
- `transfer(blockIndex)`:

  ```
  +----------+-------------+
  |   0xB0   | BLOCK_INDEX |
  | (1 byte) |  (1 byte)   |
  +----------+-------------+
  ```
- `restore(blockIndex)`:

  ```
  +----------+-------------+
  |   0xC2   | BLOCK_INDEX |
  | (1 byte) |  (1 byte)   |
  +----------+-------------+
  ```

For current NFC controllers (those that use NCI; not applicable to e.g. PN544) these commands are wrapped into special NCI commands by the Android NFC system service (see [phNxpExtns.c](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Nfc/+/android-8.1.0_r13/nci/jni/extns/pn54x/src/phNxpExtns.c) and [phNxpExtns_MifareStd.c](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Nfc/+/android-8.1.0_r13/nci/jni/extns/pn54x/src/mifare/phNxpExtns_MifareStd.c)).

Depending on why your device fails to enumerate the `MifareClassic` tag technology, you might be lucky and the NFC stack of your device already handles that wrapping. In that case, you should be able to send the above commands using the `NfcA` tag object.

However, you device might fail to enumerate the `MifareClassic` tag technology because it simply detects the tag as regular Type 2 tag (or other NFC-A tag). In that case, [NativeNfcTag.cpp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Nfc/+/android-8.1.0_r13/nci/jni/NativeNfcTag.cpp#963) will not perform the additional wrapping. You might still be able to acutally create the wrapped commands by following the same strategy that's performed in [phNxpExtns.c](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Nfc/+/android-8.1.0_r13/nci/jni/extns/pn54x/src/phNxpExtns.c) and [phNxpExtns_MifareStd.c](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Nfc/+/android-8.1.0_r13/nci/jni/extns/pn54x/src/mifare/phNxpExtns_MifareStd.c). However, I'm not sure what other side-effects the incorrect detection might have (e.g. different interface initialization).